# Сохранить файл в кодировке utf-8 java

Tags: java, кодировка

Мне нужно сохранить файл в формате .tsv чтобы у него была кодировка в utf-8, насколько это реально сделать? Делало в том что у меня есть строка в которой нет кириллических символов, только латиница и цифры.
К примеру есть строка: Test Test    Test    Test    Test    Test    Test    3. Между словами таб символ "\t".
Что я делаю:

```
File file = new File(".../test.tsv);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
os.write(attach.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
os.close();
```

Собственно файл создается, но у него кодировка ansi, если же я в строку выше добавлю хоть один символ кириллицы, тогда файл создаться с кодировкой utf-8.

Comment: Первая часть таблицы ANSI (0-127) совпадает с кодами символов UTF-8

Comment: все верно, поэтому и сохраняется в Ansi, есть ли возможность несмотря на это сохранить с кодировкой utf-8?

Comment: Это и есть кодировка utf-8. Если вы будете писать только латиницу и цифры, например, то различий с ansi и не будет.